# Improve performance of loading multiple DataTable in a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I need to load 10 dataTables in a single page, however, I am facing a performance issue whereby it takes the ard 10 seconds for all the tables to show. The performance in IE is even worse as it caused browser to hang for awhile before everything goes back to normal.

The way I am rendering these dataTables is by putting the initialize function in a for loop and looping it. As the data is retrieved from an API, I put this loop in an ajax request. Below is an example of my code. I didn't enable paging as the number of rows would at most be around 12.

```js
$.get(api_url, function(data) {
  for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    var this_data = data[index];

    $table[index] = $('.personal').on('processing.dt', function(e, settings, processing) {
      $('#processingIndicator').css('display', 'none');
      if (processing) {
        $(e.currentTarget).LoadingOverlay("show");
      } else {
        $(e.currentTarget).LoadingOverlay("hide", true);
      }
    }).DataTable({
      "data": this_data,
      'deferRender': true,
      "columns": [{
        "data": "dataOne"
      }, {
        "data": "dataTwo"
      }, {
        "data": "dataThree"
      }, {
        "data": "dataFour"
      }],
      paging: false,
      searching: false,
      ordering: false,
      info: false
    });
  }
});
```

I have searched the Datatables forum and have no luck in finding a solution to my problem. I wonder if there is any way to render the datatable asynchronously so as to prevent this lagging experience. Or is there a better way to do what I want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry @RoryMcCrossan, I dont understand what you mean. I only did one ajax request to the server, then add the data to DataTables in the front-end code. Also, sadly, all the datatables have to be visible.

Comment: In that case it sounds like a weight of data issue